Debugger is not moving from one web application to a service (which is in another web application)in Visual Studio
I am using 2 web applications. Web application1 is taking data from web application2. But while I debugged web application1, the debugger is not  hitting web application 2 (it goes to next line in application1).
Could some one help me with this issue?

Your question lacks significant relevant information. Are these web application projects in the same solution? Did you run them both in the debugger at the same time? Assuming they are both in the same solution, you should configure the solution to have at least those two as startup projects, so you can debug both at the same time in the same VS instance.

@jmcilhinney There are in different solution.

So how did you actually run them such that you expected them both to be debugged? Like I said, your question lacks information. Provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. What you're actually doing is obviously relevant information.

We need to see a [mcve] to have any hope of answering this question.

First, you have two different solutions, so you should open two Visual Studios and run them separately.
Then, open breakpoints at both the Web1 request data and the Web2 return data.
Finally, you need to make sure the network request to get the data is correct.
